# How to display the last records of the user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and I have more than 100 records in the table. I have the same records but the date of added is different.

Table is

```
m_id | member_id  | c_k   | b_k  | date_of_added
1    | 101        | qwer  |sdad1 | 14-02-2019 02:26:30
2    | 101        | qwe2  |sdad2 | 14-02-2019 03:30:20
3    | 102        | qweg  |sdad3 | 14-02-2019 04:00:40
4    | 101        | qwe3  |sdad4 | 14-02-2019 04:30:20
5    | 102        | qweg  |sdad5 | 14-02-2019 05:45:30
```

I tried below query but it's displaying all the records related to the member_id=101. I need a last record of the member_id.

```
SELECT * from m_details WHERE member_id=101 GROUP by member_id ORDER BY date_of_added DESC
```

My expected output is

```
m_id | member_id  | c_k   | b_k  | date_of_added
4    | 101        | qwe3  |sdad4 | 14-02-2019 04:30:20
```

Would you help me out what is wrong with the query?

Tagging PHP team because I am working on PHP but getting the issue in query.

Comment: Take the GROUP BY out and add `LIMIT 1`

Comment: I remove the group by but I got all the records. Ok so I have to use LIMIT 1...let me try this

Comment: Kindly upvote the answers that helped you, it motivates people to keep up :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead :

```
SELECT * // Gets everything
FROM m_details // From your table
WHERE member_id=101 // For member #101
ORDER BY date_of_added DESC // Gets the last result 
LIMIT 1 // Only shows that result
```

Comment: *This* is a basic query. The overlapping range problem is at least a level up from this.

Comment: @Strawberry in an interview this or that are both basic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY member_id  ORDER BY date_of_added DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) WHERE member_id=101 AND rn = 1
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will work even if you need to display the information for more than on logic, as opposite to the `GROUP BY`/`LIMIT` solution, that only works for a single user at a time.

In earlier versions of MySQL, this can also be implemented using a `NOT EXISTS` condition :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE 
    t.member_id = 101
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM mytable t1 
        WHERE t1.member_id = t.member_id AND t1.date_of_added > t.date_of_added
    )
```

Comment: Only if the OP is using MySQL 8>

Comment: Would be interested to know which was more efficient between yours and mine, but mine is definitely easier to write :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Yes, you are correct, Your query is easy to understand.

Comment: @user9437856 : yes I agree that RiggsFolly's solution is easier to read. Mine, however, would also work if you need to recover the information for more than one user (you would just need to remove `t.member_id = 101` from the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. You just need to use [`LIMIT 1`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html), if you need the last record:

```
SELECT * from m_details WHERE member_id=101 GROUP by member_id ORDER BY date_of_added DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY member_id` is not standard SQL and will not work on recent versions of MySQL, unless you tweak it.

Comment: @GMB Does it slow down the query and why it will not work with recent versions?

Comment: See [this](https://medium.com/@riccardoodone/the-love-hate-relationship-between-select-and-group-by-in-sql-4957b2a70229)

Comment: @GMB Thanks for the explanation. So do you want me to correct this query? :)

Comment: You do want to correct it, because it might mislead other people. But then it would be identical to some of the other answers (on this question, I think 5 answers already gave the same solution)... *Maybe* it would be a better idea to just delete it... Your decision anyway !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from m_details 
WHERE member_id=101 
ORDER BY date_of_added DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The GROUP BY is just obscuring the result because it does not necessarily pick the data from the last row it finds.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get the only one latest record, use `DESC` and `LIMIT = 1` as below:

```
SELECT * from m_details WHERE member_id = 101 ORDER BY date_of_added DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY member_id` is not standard SQL and will not work on recent versions of MySQL, unless you tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from m_details WHERE member_id=101 ORDER BY m_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Using the above query for expected output. In this case, does not need to group by clause.

Comment: What if the record with the highest `date_of_added ` is not the one with the highest `m_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

As `member_id` can have duplicate value(according to your given dataset), you can identify `m_id` column as unique and (auto) increasing value(it seems so) and sort based on that column in descending order to get the updated value and then just pick the first row by setting `LIMIT 1`. So write your query removing `group by` clause:

```
SELECT * from m_details WHERE member_id=101 order by m_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Hope, this will help.
N.B.: It seems that new entries can't have lower `date_of_added` value than previous as there is no specific info about that, otherwise sort by `date_of_added`

Comment: Same answer was already posted 25 minutes ago by RohitUrane. Also, what if the record with the highest `date_of_added ` is not the one with the highest `m_id` ?

Comment: ok.. I was just editing my answer about that. As there is no such  info and sample dataset seems it can't   be like that, that's why I pointed that. thanks.